# Accessing Files From JSP inside WEB-INF

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I have a `.jsp` called by a servlet to process data.
I am trying to test it with a local file, and my directory currently looks like this:

```
WEB-INF
    |----jsp
        |----test.jsp
    |----data.txt
```

My `.jsp` is not even able to do a basic file read:

```
<%
    String in = "../data.txt";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
    out.println(br.readLine());
%>
```

I have also tried many other variations:

```
= "data.txt"
= "./data.txt"
= "/data.txt"
= "file:///data.txt"
= "file://data.txt"
= "WEB-INF/data.txt"
```

etc., and have not been able to read from the file.
I am still new to servlets so I am probably missing a key interaction here and would be grateful if someone could show me basically the canonical "hello world" version of how to access a file from a `.jsp` in `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Test this:

```
<%
    // application is JSP variable point to ServletContext instance

    InputStream is = application.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/data.txt");

    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ));

    out.println(br.readLine());
%>
```

Comment: Never use and suggest *Scriplet* in 21st century instead use [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

Comment: @Braj In his defense he did offer a solution that the op was asking for.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues here.

1. Most important is that JSP is display technology. You shouldn't be trying to do anything in a jsp that's more than just displaying some data provided by the environment (such as properties on the `HttpResponse` that were set by a servlet). You certainly shouldn't be trying to access the file system from a jsp.
2. Even from a servlet, you shouldn't do that. You should put the file in the classpath, and use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource` or `getResourceAsStream`. Accessing a file in the file system directly from a web app can be done, but it's not recommended, and not portable.

Edit: @LocHa's answer will probably work, but you really shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the information! This is purely for testing purposes. In the actual production code I receive a data stream.

Comment: @K.R.S. it doesn't matter the data source, but where you use it. And JSP is not the solution **ever**.

Comment: I will eventually be receiving data through EJBs to my servlets. I am waiting on others to write the EJBs though so I am temporarily using a .jsp to process a file into JSON for testing. Yes, bad, I know.

Comment: Bad practice, even short-term. Repeat after me..."JSP is a DISPLAY technology"...

And BTW, you shouldn't reference an EJB in your jsp either, because JSP is a DISPLAY technology.

Comment: Yes, I have already admitted it is bad practice, no need to caps. Best practices should only be applied when they make sense and in my case I decided it did not. Maybe you disagree, but I cannot accept this kind of answer as solution.

See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256314/is-it-bad-to-answer-dont-do-this-it-is-bad-android-design

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` to get the actual file system path of your file.
The `ServletContext` is accessible from a .jsp under the name `application`.

So you should do :

```
<%
    String in = application.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(in));
    out.println(br.readLine());
%>
```